# C preprocessor using the closing bracket of a parent macro

Tags: c, macros, c99, c-preprocessor

I have this code which works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define A(x) x B
#define B(x) C(x,
#define C(x,y) y x)
int main( void ) {
    printf( A("1") ("2") "3" );
}
```

It prints `132` (the point of the `A` macro is to swap the thing which follows its parameters in brackets with everything after that until another closing bracket)

But if I use that within another macro:

```
#define Z(x) x
printf( Z( A("1") ("2") "3" ) );
```

I get the compile error "Unterminated function-like macro invocation".

I realise that this happens because the compiler is trying to process the arguments of `Z` independently, but I need to use its closing bracket as a marker. Is there a way I can make this work within macros? Changing the calling syntax isn't really an option.

---

p.s. Before I get any responses talking about what an awful thing this is to do, rest assured: this is not for real code. It is a problem which came up while making a toy program which uses `define` to simulate a new language inside C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to see what's going on is to change the test case a little.

```
#define A(x) x B
#define B(x) C(x,
#define C(x,y) y x]  /* note close square bracket instead of close paren */

Y(A(1)(2)3)
```

preprocesses to `Y(1 3 2]`.  This is because an intermediate stage of expansion looked like

```
Y(1 C(2,3)
```

at which point `C` ate the close paren *that appeared to belong to `Y` in the original text* and replaced it with a close bracket.

Now, what happens differently if `A(1)(2)3` is inside a macro argument?

```
#define Z(x) x
Z(A(1)(2)3)
```

Because of [argument prescan](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan), the analogous intermediate stage of expansion is *not*

```
Z(1 C(2,3)
```

but rather

```
1 C(2,3
```

with `Z` squirrelled away on a hidden "pending expansions" stack.  The preprocessor is, in effect, *enforcing* the textual appearance that that final close paren belongs to `Z`, and `C` is not allowed to borrow it.

The least-invasive way I can think of to achieve your original goal is

```
#define _A(x) x B
#define B(x) C(x,
#define C(x,y) y x)

#define Z(x) ZZ((_##x))
#define ZZ(x) ZZZ x
#define ZZZ(x) [x]

Z(A(1)(2)3)
```

preprocesses to `[1 3 2]`.  We use the token paste operator to prevent `Z`'s argument from being prescanned, so we can add a temporary extra set of parentheses for use by `C`.  `ZZ` and `ZZZ` then strip them off again.  The catch is that it's an error if you don't paste `x` with *something*, so we have to add a leading underscore to the definition of `A`, and it will be an error if the first token of `Z`'s argument is ever not something that can be token-pasted after an underscore.

You might want to consider using [M4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) instead of trying to shoehorn this into the C preprocessor.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation. Unfortunately the solution isn't applicable to my exact problem (I still need other macros inside Z to expand). As for M4, well if this was a real project I'd agree but the challenge is to do this with C's bizarre preprocessor! As a related question, would it be possible to use `()` brackets instead of `[]`? i.e. is there a way to escape bracket characters?

Comment: I don't understand your related question.  I was just using square brackets for illustration; as far as the preprocessor is concerned they have no special significance whatsoever.

Comment: I mean this line: `#define C(x,y) y x]  /* note close square bracket instead of close paren */` as a `)`, it breaks.

Comment: No, wait, I misunderstood. Ignore that.

Answer (score 2):

eclipse cdt is excellent to debug your questions. for eclipse, just hover over a macro to get started. here is detialed info on it:

[C/C++ Software Development with Eclipse >> 2.1.7. Macro Expansion](http://eclipsebook.in/c-cpp-development/reading-code/macro-expansions/)

for your second macro, eclipse shows the following:

```
int main (void) {
    printf( Z( A("1") ("2") "3" ) );
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Spotting the Error**

Notice in the expansion #3 C("2", "3" just 'disappears. I take this as CDT's way of saying 'unterminated argument list'. Whatever the case for it disappearing, this is the method I prefer to take when debugging macros.

- Using this tool makes it clear that in Expansion#2 (third image) we have an unterminated set of brackets, thus locating the error.

**Understanding a Solution**

After fiddling around a bit using this tool, I think this is what you were after:

```
printf( Z( (A("1") ("2") "3") ) );

yields (using gcc -E main.c -c)

printf( ("1" "3" "2") );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is about the order in which the macros are processed. The simplest solution is to add additional parentheses around the `Z` argument.

```
    printf( Z( (A("1")("2") "3")) );
```

Comment: But would it be possible to do that *without* requiring a different syntax when used? (possibly by making `Z` into a more complicated macro).