# Error when defining a simple macro in c++

Tags: c++, macros

I'm new with using macros in c++. I wrote a short macro and I don't know what is wrong with it. Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define start B(
#define end )
#define B(x) cout<<x; 


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    start 2014 end
}
```

Comment: Error 4 error C2059: syntax error : ')' 
Error 2 error C2059: syntax error : ';'

Comment: possible duplicate of [C preprocessor using the closing bracket of a parent macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862490/c-preprocessor-using-the-closing-bracket-of-a-parent-macro)

Comment: add ; to the end )    => end );

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C preprocessor does not work the way you expect.  Macros are expanded in *one pass*, that means that the preprocessor will substitute "start" with "B(" and "end" with ")" and give the result to the compiler.

Since there is no second preprocessing pass, the intermediate result "B(2014)" will not be interpreted as a preprocessor macro.  Instead, the C++ compiler sees a function call, which is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But if it goes in one pass why does this work:
    #define start B
    #define end ;
    #define B(x) cout<<x;
    int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {
 start (2014) end

Comment: @user3132631 `start` will be expanded to `B`, recognized to be a macro name, and expanded again, _in the same pass_. `end` is not required here, by the way, since it will be expanded to a superfluous semicolon.

Comment: ok that makes sence.. is there a trick that i can avoid brackets and I could write code like i wanted  "start 2014 end"

Comment: @klem Depending on what you are trying to do, you could use operator overloading: `#define start std::cout <<`, `#define end <<std::endl;`.  The best advice I can give you: Don't even try that.  Use macros as little as possible, since they are *evil*. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/preprocessor-is-evil.html

Comment: my electrical engineer boss frowns at me when I call things evil :(